# Java Selection Sort Swap Count

Tags: java, selection-sort

I have this code and need a little help figuring out the count of the swaps. I think I need a for loop where it is mark but I don't quit understand how to extract the swap count. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Selection
{
    public static void SelectionSort ( int [ ] num, int howmany )
    { 
        int i, j, first, temp;  
        int comparecount = 0;
        int swapcount = 0;

        for ( i = num.length - 1; i > 0; i-- )  
        {   
            first = 0;   
            for(j = 1; j <= i; j ++)   
            {  
                comparecount++;

                if( num[ j ] < num[ first ] )         
                    first = j;
            }
            temp = num[ first ];   //need to count swaps ???
            num[ first ] = num[ i ];
            num[ i ] = temp; 
        }

        System.out.print(comparecount);
        System.out.print(swapcount);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you not just increment `swapcount` at your comment??

Comment: also where is `int howmany` used? why is it there?

Comment: I was passing it in for something else and didn't delete it

Comment: As for the swapcount at the comment I get 122549 which, I don't think is right.

Comment: Homework? Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409436/sort-comparisons-counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have answered your own question. You say you want to count the swaps, then have put a comment exactly where you swap items.... so just increment the swapcount there.

As a display error you are using print as opposed to println, which is making your numbers appear side by side and indistinguishable from each other

Comment: As for the swapcount at the comment I get 122549 which, I don't think is right.

Comment: how many elements are you sorting? it really could be right.  Remember selection sort is a N^2 algorithm, so if you have more than 400 elements its very likely to take this many.

Comment: The problem is you are using print as println.  which mean you print out the comparecount and swap count side by side.  This makes the number look much bigger than it really is. I updated my answer with this as well

Comment: I just realize this as well. sorry everyone