# java mergesort count homework

Tags: java, mergesort

I am working on getting the counts of comparisons and movers when merge sorting. I think I have the recursion I need thanks to this [Sort Comparisons Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409436/sort-comparisons-counter) but I can not get it to print out.  I am obviously very new at programming so I'd be appreciative if you could explain what it is that I am missing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MergeSort {
int count = 0;
/**
 * @param args
 */

// Rearranges the elements of a into sorted order using
// the merge sort algorithm (recursive).
public int mergeSort(int[] a, int howMany) {


    if (a.length >= 2) {
        // split array into two halves
        int[] left  = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length/2);
        int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, a.length/2, a.length);


        // sort the two halves
       howMany = mergeSort(left,howMany);
       howMany = mergeSort(right, howMany);

        // merge the sorted halves into a sorted whole
       howMany = merge ( left, right, a, howMany);


    }

   return howMany;
}




// Merges the left/right elements into a sorted result.
// Precondition: left/right are sorted
public static int merge(int[] result, int[] left, 
                                       int[] right, int howMany) {
    int i1 = 0;   // index into left array
    int i2 = 0;   // index into right array

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (i2 >= right.length ||
           (i1 < left.length && left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
            result[i] = left[i1];    // take from left
            i1++;
        } else {
            result[i] = right[i2];   // take from right
            i2++;
        }

    }

    return howMany;
}

System.out.println(howMany); // ???
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String []args){
   System.out.println(callYouMethodHere(foo,bar));
}

Comment: Sprinkle a few more `System.out.println` statements throughout to see that your code is working as you think it should.

Comment: what is the call order of methods? normally main method will be called first, but i think you are doing the opposite . and the System.out.println is after the return statement and it wont execute any way

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the method through its object wherever you wanna print. something like this (may be in your main method):

```
MergeSort mObj - new MergeSort();
int[] array = {1,2,3};
int count =  mObj.mergeSort(array, 2);
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a driver method. When a java class is run, it will look for a `public static void main(String[] args)` method; if this method doesn't exist, nothing will happen. With what you have now, you should actually get a compile error from `System.out.println(howMany);` since the variable `howMany` only exists within the scope (brackets) of the merge method. To understand this better I'd review your notes on variable and method scope and class members. For a quick fix, remove the line at the bottom that I mentioned above, and place this method somewhere in your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {2,5,8,1,3};
    int howMany = mergeSort(array, 5);
    System.out.println(howMany);
}
```

You also need to make your `mergeSort` method `static`, so change its definition to

`public **static** int mergeSort(int[] a, int howMany)`

I tested your code and I'm pretty sure that it doesn't give the answer you want, so be sure to check that. Best of luck learning object oriented programming!